# Is it possible to create a .NET Datatable in VBScript?

Tags: .net, vbscript, datatable

I have a rest API returning a Datatable, this includes the schema information with it. Here is an example:

```
<DataSet>
  <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="qryVentListMapping">
    <xs:element name="qryVentListMapping" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="qryVentListMapping" msdata:CaseSensitive="False" msdata:Locale="en-US">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="VentMapId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="VentID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="PatientID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="RoomID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="Unit" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="DeviceCategory" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="VentType" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="VentModel" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="IsActive" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="RoomSeq" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="DispOrder" type="xs:double" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <qryVentListMapping>
      <qryVentListMapping diffgr:id="qryVentListMapping1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
        <VentMapId />
        <VentID />
        <PatientID />
        <RoomID />
        <Unit>1</Unit>
        <DeviceCategory />
        <VentType />
        <VentModel />
        <IsActive>true</IsActive>
        <RoomSeq />
        <DispOrder />
      </qryVentListMapping>
    </qryVentListMapping>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Now I have tried this:

```
Set dt = CreateObject("System.Data.DataTable")
 dt.ReadXml(objHttp.ResponseText)
```

But it give me this error:

> ActiveX component can't create object - Microsoft VBScript runtime
>   error

Is there any easy way to deserialize this into something usable in an object without having to load it into a XML document and parse through it (witch i do have working)? The XML returned is sometimes thousands of lines and the function that this is in is called every couple seconds. This is causing high CPU load. I need a more elegant way of dealing with the massive amount of data.

EDIT: Here is the working function I am using now. I am loading everything into a Recordset and using as a replacement of the table.

```
Function GetRecordSet(PARAMS, Qry)

    Dim objXML, rs, child, node, qryNode
    Dim URL
    URL = APPLICATION("UIDS_URL") & PARAMS
    Set objXML = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
    objXML.setProperty "ServerHTTPRequest", True
    objXML.async =  False
    objXML.Load URL
    Err.number = objXML.parseError.errorCode 
    objXML.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"

    dim objNodeList : Set objNodeList = objXML.selectNodes( "//"&Qry ) 

    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.CursorType = 1 ' adOpenKeyset
        rs.LockType = 4 ' adLockBatchOptimistic
        rs.CursorLocation = 2 'adUseClient

    If 0 <> objNodeList.length Then 


        set qryNode = objNodeList(0)

        Set node = objXML.selectSingleNode("//"&Qry)
        For Each child in node.ChildNodes            
            rs.Fields.Append child.NodeName, 8, 10, 4             
        Next   

        rs.open   

        For Each node in objNodeList
            rs.AddNew          
            For Each child in node.ChildNodes            
                rs.Fields(child.NodeName).Value = child.Text  

            Next
            rs.Update   
        Next  
        Set rs.ActiveConnection = Nothing
        rs.MoveFirst    

    end if        

   Set GetRecordSet = rs   

End Function
```

Example usage of the function:

```
Set rs = GetRecordSet ("CQryVentDataDetail?VentId="&VentId&"&InputValue="&InputValue, "qryVentDataDetail")
```

Comment: Depending on how the function looks that you have working there might be ways of improving its performance. Maybe it's best if you include that as well.

Comment: Thanks I updated the question with the currently "Working" code.

Comment: Is it necessary to re-download and re-parse the entire response for every XPath query you want to make?

Comment: Yes unfortunately this is for a biomedical application and it involves patient safety. if the data changes the page needs to be updated. Also, the request is not always the same. As you can see the endpoint of the api is passed into the function.

Comment: Right, but I figured your application (i.e. the part of the code that calls `GetRecordSet()`) might want to query the same page of data twice in a row. Anyway, I maybe have an idea how to improve this. Could you include a sample of a typical `qry` value? Also, is this used in classic ASP or in a different environment?

Comment: Sure added an example of the usage to the question.

Comment: Is working with the XML nodes themselves out of the question for you? Because, if all you do is iterate them and render their values to a page, then this can easily be done with the node list that `.selectNodes` would return. If you want to turn the server's result to HTML as your primary use case then I would recommend using XSLT over implementing you own HTML generation code in VBScript.

Comment: I did end up using the xml object. It was a lot of work to convert everything that's why its taken me so long to respond. I have a bit more to go and a few more kinks to work out but it looks like its going to work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If you have target HTML to work with I'd whip up some XSLT. This probably is the fastet option you have.